# How to track Facebook iframe video on my site with Google Analytics?

Tags: facebook, video, iframe, google-analytics, tracking

I have this video implemented on my website:

```
<iframe allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" height="400" scrolling="no" src="..." style="border:none;overflow:hidden" width="560"></iframe>
```

What I want to do is to track how many people play the video and watch it full time or at least 1 minute.

I have tried with Event Tracking, but this way is not accurate, because the tracking code I have implemented will be working when the whole iframe is clicked, which is no guarantee that the video will be played.

Actually this method does not work at all.

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Hi, typically if you aren't able to get your tracking code served through the iframe itself, then you won't be able to track any type of engagement.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the cross-origin nature of your iframe, you won't be able to track the video clicks inside it. You could fire an event when the iframe loads...but as you mentioned, that's not an accurate measure of "plays"

You could upload your video to YouTube, and use the YouTube iFrame API to create and track video plays on your website via Google Analytics Events.

As far as I'm aware, Facebook doesn't have anything similar for their embeds...but I could be wrong.